# Calculate application CRC from memory

Tags: c#, memory, crc

How to read application CRC from memory not from executable file because somebody can patch application when its run? i Use C#

Comment: Sounds like you are doing this to protect against piracy. What's to stop someone from patching your CRC code?

Comment: You might be better off just signing the assembly with a strong name. It's easier, and probably more effective than a simple crc.

Comment: What are you going to compare it against?

Comment: @Brook it is *very* easy to remove strong name signatures from an assembly using something like [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil).

Comment: @vcsjones - Yes, but you can add code to your application that verifies that it is strong name signed. It's an officially supported mechanism in .NET and will be just as difficult (or not) to circumvent as a CRC check. See http://www.csharp411.com/determine-if-a-loaded-net-assembly-is-signed/

Comment: @vcsjones: sure, but so would any sort of crc on the exe.  At least the signing is built into .Net and easy to do.  If you really want protection you've got to spend some $$ on a good obfuscator/protector.

Comment: to patch a running application the one patching it must have very high priviliges (Administrator plus elevation...) - so in this specific scenario none (signing and/or CRC) will help... one option would be to use a custom "cross-compiler" (for a custom VM, not IL!), a custom loader (native) which in turn runs the application in the custom VM... something like this is offered by MS for enterprise customers, rather costly...

Comment: Do you want to completely disable patching (you can't), or just make it slightly harder?

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea...